# XSLT 1.0 multiple call of a template

Tags: xslt-1.0

I need to replace strings in an XML file. I'm trying to use XSLT to do it. I want to use call-template for each string I need to replace.

When I make multiple call to the template, only the last call works fine.

The XML file I need to change : I want to replace the strings

```
&#145;
```

and

```
&#151;
```

by spaces

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RAPPORT>
    <reason>start test_145 : &#145; and test_ 151 : &#151; _end_test</reason>
</RAPPORT>
```

The template I use :

```
    <xsl:template name="globalReplace">
        <xsl:param name="outputString"/>
        <xsl:param name="target"/>
        <xsl:param name="replacement"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($outputString,$target)">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($outputString,$target),$replacement)"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="globalReplace">
                    <xsl:with-param name="outputString" select="substring-after($outputString,$target)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="target" select="$target"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="replacement" select="$replacement"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$outputString"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

The multiple calls :

```
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:call-template name="globalReplace">
            <xsl:with-param name="outputString" select="."/>
            <xsl:with-param name="target" select="'&#145;'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="replacement" select="' '"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:call-template name="globalReplace">
            <xsl:with-param name="outputString" select="."/>
            <xsl:with-param name="target" select="'&#151;'"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="replacement" select="' '"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
```

Expected result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RAPPORT>
    <reason>debut test_test_145  et test 151 _fin test</reason>
</RAPPORT>
```

What I get in fact :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RAPPORT>
    <reason>debut test_test_145**PUI** et test 151 _fin test</reason>
</RAPPORT>
```

**PUI** means an unexpected character instead of the needed space

Comment: The "unexpected character" you observe is the control character whose Unicode decimal code is `145`. It wasn't replaced, because your 1st template matching `text()` was never applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two templates that **match** `text()`. Only the last  of these is applied - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#conflict

In the given example, you could simply use the `translate()` function to do all the work at once, since the "strings" you want to replace are actually characters:

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RAPPORT>
    <reason>start test_145 : &#145; and test_ 151 : &#151; _end_test</reason>
</RAPPORT>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '&#145;&#151;', '  ')"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RAPPORT>
  <reason>start test_145 :   and test_ 151 :  _end_test</reason>
</RAPPORT>
```

Comment: Many thanks !
It works fine this way !
I improved it inserting my result into a variable :

` <xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:variable name="premierePasse">
   <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '&#145;&#151;&#146;','   ')"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="translate($premierePasse, '&#156;', 'œ')"/>
 </xsl:template>`

Comment: It can still be done in one pass: `<xsl:value-of select="translate(., '&#145;&#151;&#146;&#156;' ,'___œ')"/>`  (I am using underscores here instead of spaces)..

Comment: Works fine ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks !
It works fine this way !
I improved it inserting my result into a variable :

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:variable name="premierePasse">
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '&#145;&#151;&#146;','   ')"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate($premierePasse, '&#156;', 'œ')"/>
    </xsl:template>
```